# jQuery animate() pulse() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, pulse

In the following code, the `animate()` function in `click()` works.
However, `animate()` or `pulse()` (when uncommented) in `mouseenter()` does not work either.
The `pulse()` function is provided by Jarrod Overson...

http://jarrodoverson.com/static/demos/jquery.pulse.html

```
    sectionTitle = $j(this).find(".sectionTitle");
    sectionTitle.click(function(){
    if($j(this).parent().height() == sections[$j(this).parent().attr("id")]["height"]){
        origHeight = sections[$j(this).parent().attr("id")]["origHeight"];
        $j(this).parent().animate({height:origHeight},"slow");
    }else{
        height = sections[$j(this).parent().attr("id")]["height"];
        $j(this).parent().animate({height:height},"slow");
    }
    })
    sectionTitle.mouseenter(function(){
    var properties = { "color" : '#F00' };
  //    $j(this).pulse(properties, 500, 3);
    $j(this).animate({"background-color":'#F00'},"slow");
    })
```

A live example of my code is here. 
http://fantasticvisions.net/test/me/

The classs `sectionTitle` is applied to a number of the H2 elements on the above page. Clicking them will cause the content to expand, using jQuery `animate()`. However, the `mouseenter()` fails.

What am I missing here? I have tried a number of other variations on this, and none work. The `mouseenter()` event does fire, and the code is executed (I have traced this) but the effect never seems to happen.

Comment: What am I missing here?  How can we expect `.pulse()` to work when you have it commented out?  I mean, if you want help, perhaps providing a demo of the actual code without critical sections commented out would be best.

Comment: Sparky672 you are a bit quick off the mark. Please re-read the post. It specifically mentions pulse() (when uncommented) does not work. That then means, you would in turn comment out the animate.

Also the post also provides a live example, but since you missed it the first time, here it is again. http://fantasticvisions.net/test/me/

Comment: Since you missed this part of my comment, here it is again:  _"if you want help, perhaps providing a demo of the actual code **without critical sections commented out** would be best"_. `pulse` is clearly commented out in [your live example](http://fantasticvisions.net/test/me/).  If you want help, post a proper example.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: And again, if you read the post carefully, it states, **neither** animate() or pulse() were working. However JeffB has provided the solution. I had not included **JQuery UI**.
Thanks for trying any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.animate()` is not working because jQuery by itself does not support animation of colors.

If you include jQuery UI, or a color animation plugin, this should work.

Comment: Thanks JeffB! That was it. 8)